# understanding probability distribution notation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume that $\mu$ is a probability distribution on $[n]$, let $A\subseteq[n] $ be a probability event. What does it mean : $Pr_\mu[A]$ ?

Comment: Let $A$ be an even what?

Comment: it's probability event ! but @Did give a good interpretation of $Pr_\mu [A] $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is $\mu(A)=\sum\limits_{k\in A}\mu(\{k\})$.